# Интеграция Google play billing в андроид приложение

Tags: android

В одном из приложений реализована разовая покупка (отключение рекламы) через библиотеку inn-app billing. От гугл пришло письмо что нужно перейти на google play billing. Подскажите пожалуйста или скиньте ссылки на примеры где реализована разовая покупка в приложении и чтобы при запуске приложения была проверка на то что покупка совершена или нет.

Comment: По идее вам любой пример подойдёт или даже просто документация. Если у вас уже всё реализовано, то заменить либу по документации не займёт много времени. Часа 2-3 если в первый раз и если не очень понятно что происходит.

Comment: Хочу перейти без миграции на гугловскую. Если нетрудно можете словами алгоритм описать? Подключить в gradle библиотеку - какие дальнейшие действия? Никогда не работал с этим и в своем приложении из курса взял куски внедрил. От андроида в последнее время отошел и времени на изучение чего-то нового практически нет.

Comment: Если у вас уже есть встроенная покупка - вы уже используете библиоетку от гугла. Иначе - никак не выйдет - придётся продолжать пользоваться гугловыми либами. Краткий алгоритм - создаёте объект либы, через него соеденитесь с сервисами гугла, после установки соединения - вызывайте методы получения имеющихся у юзера покупок, инициации новой покупки, подтверждения совершённой покупки. Вроде как не сложно - вызвать 4 метода, обработать 3 колбэка.

Comment: Без изучения нового никак не выйдет - гугл постоянно всё меняет, и если не бежать с задаваемой им скоростью - приложение будет из магазина удалено за нарушение правил и аккаунт будет забанен. Правда, даже если все требования выполнять - забанить вас всё равно в любой момент могут, т.к. гугл - зло.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.